# C++ how to wrap a variadic function template's parameter pack -> into a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

I want to build a **functon template** that takes any function pointer & its arguments list - and returns a (stateful) lambda that binds those arguments values inside (think std::bind but lambda-based)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class ...D>
class DEB;

template <class Ret, class ... Args>
auto getLambdaFromFunction(Ret(*func)(Args...)) {
    return [func](Args ... ar){ // auto could work here but lambda is anyway templated by external template's Args
        func(ar...);
    };
}

template <class Ret, class ... Args>
auto wrapFunction(Ret(*func)(Args...),Args... args) {
    return [=](){
        func(args...);
    };
}

int doone(int a, float b) {
    std::cout << "do one";
    return a;
}

int main() {
    auto lw = getLambdaFromFunction(doone); // compiles
    lw(1,2.); // invokation works

    auto lambda_parameters_binded = wrapFunction(doone, 1,2.); // **ERROR**: no matching function for call
lambda_parameters_binded(); // see mom, no hands ie no arguments!
}
```

I believe I need to make somehow the variadic arguments to be captured inside the lambda in wrapFunction
the default [=] capture seems not to understand variadic argument list

Comment: You should be able to expand the parameter pack in the lambda's capture - see Lambda Captures [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: @mattnewport so when I refer to the parameter pack inside the lambda's body when calling func(args...) - it should automatically expand all of its elements to the lambda's  [=] capture , right? everything should work out of the box?

Comment: @mattnewport I just tried to write return [func,args...](){  func(args...); };   -- but still its not binding to the wrapFunction template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the error description carefully, right now function accepts float, but you are passing double as a third parameter. Passing float will make it work:

```
auto lambda_parameters_binded = wrapFunction(doone, 1, 2.0f);
```

[Run in online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cFgbof8c9fVZm7Nr)

Also note that generated lambda does not return anything, you should add another return statement inside of lambda body:

```
return
(
    [=](void)
    {
        return(func(args...));
    }
);
```

Comment: hmmm... shouldn't it just auto-narrow to float? as in ordinary function call

Comment: @barney Actually function arguments (as is) will be used for template parameters deduction. From first function argument they may seem to be `int int float` but from the rest of arguments they may seem to be `int int double`. Template parameters deduction does not deal with such conflicts and just fails. It does not work as compiler deduced `Args` to be `int float` from first function argument and then adjusted second and third function arguments to match.

Comment: I see. So the function template arguments deduction just silently fails by SFINAE because of this conflict - and that leads to absence of any instantiations of such a function -> so there are no options to auto-narrow because the compiler just doesn't find any similar function signatures. Wow, this is insightful. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to have the function parameters, and the passed in parameter in different variadic template packs. That way there will be no ambiguity to generate the template function.

```
template <class Ret, class ... Args, class ... Params>
auto wrapFunction(Ret(*func)(Args...),Params... params) {
    return [=](){
        func(params...);
    };
}
```

Comment: interesting solution! I even couldn't thought that it is possible. This way the function is parametrized by its pointer's type's signature and parameters are picked on their own - so they could be narrowed to their possible casts. Cool indeed! The world of templates is very flexible in many surprising ways...